# Is there a way in Linux to replace a command name into other name?

Tags: linux, security, command

Escenario: What if a non authorized person (hacker) after break into the system could not use the "ls" command (or other basic commands)?
Not much he can do, right?

So, is it possible to replace the name of a command like "ls" for other name? (not create an alias)

Comment: Replace it and do what? Break all the other uses of `ls`?

Comment: Security by obscurity is not security.

Comment: I can do plenty on your site without `ls`. Bash `echo *`; `find /home`; `tree`; even `tar cvf - >/dev/null`. But usually, I just tar the whole /home directory off to my machine, and then use the tools I have here.

Comment: It's a fair question. Apart from SbO  not being recommended, renaming the command does not make it impossible to use it. It can be tracked by known dependencies (assuming it was changed in all its dependents). Specially for popular and opensource OS's.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, you may change the name of the `ls` command if you wish.  You would do this with `mv` as root, just like you would change the name of any other file.  However, you will no longer be able to use `ls` with the name `ls`, and neither would any scripts etc.

As long as you're happy to maintain a system where `ls` is called `02134` and `cp` is called `ntoe1` etc., then you can do so.  Maintaining such a system would include having to patch any software that you install so that your own special names are used in place of the standard names.  This would also include patching the available shells on the system so that *built-in* utilities like `echo`, `cd`, and others, have new names too.

In the end, this only amounts to [security through obscurity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Security_through_obscurity), which is generally no security at all, and at best a temporary slow-down measure (akin to a pad-lock on a door or bike). The first thing an intruder would need to do would be to transfer a set of properly named statically linked tools to a local directory, and use them instead.

If you have an intruder in your system, then you have already lost. It would be better to spend time securing network and physical access to prevent that intrusion from happening at all.

Comment: I agree with this answer, but would add for OP, what happens when you do an upgrade? You did not say which linux you use, but lets assume something with system updates, like Debian or RedHat derivatives. After an "update world" (I guess my gentoo genes are showing), the system might update "ls" and "cd" and those would get installed again. You would need to automate all of your renaming  so that after an update they would be changed back to your obfuscated state.

Comment: @number9 Thanks. This is what I alluded to with "[...] having to patch any software that you install [...]".

Answer (score 0):

> What if a non authorized person (hacker)

The word you're looking for is "cracker", "criminal" or "intruder", not ["hacker"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hacker).

> after break into the system could not use the "ls" command (or other basic commands)? Not much he can do, right?

Except that if the break-in happens through a software bug that allows the intruder to execute arbitrary code, it's just that, anything they like. They don't need to start a shell, they don't need to use `ls`. They might want to, just for ease of use, but they could instead just call the raw system calls necessary to install software of their choosing, and that could be e.g. Busybox which comes with `ls` and all other commonly-used command line tools, or some dedicated software of their own.

Considering installing tools of their own, I'd be more worried about `wget` and `curl`, than `ls`.

Of course, making your system unusual or lacking common tools might make an intruder with sufficiently low motivation go away, but that's really only useful after you're already compromised.